# Как мне раcшифровать .dat файл

Tags: javascript, node.js, decode

Мне нужно расшифровать dat файл таким образом:

`.dat -> xor (ключ 11) -> base64 -> zlib -> plaintext`

и по возможности перекодировать обратно.

Comment: xor (ключ 11) — это должно применяться к каждому байту? Может, дадите краткий пример — исходные байты и текст, который из них должен получиться? Чтобы пытающиеся помочь могли тестировать своё решение

Comment: https://pastebin.com/JakxXUVG, вот код на пайтоне, но мне нужно на node.js

Comment: Возможно, вы быстрее получите ответ, если создадите новый вопрос с просьбой трансформировать код из Python в js, с метками обоих языков. Я не знаю Python, но мне кажется, там ещё какие-то манипуляции производятся с заменами символов. И используются определённые настройки для zlib.

Comment: тогда я думаю мне будет проще выполнить код пайтона через js, и я зря написал этот вопрос.

Comment: Обратно кстати корректно кодировать не получится. Сейчас после декодирования base64 на вход zlib.decompress подаются данные с 10 байта. По алгоритму не ясно что же было в отброшенных 10 байтах в начале. А при кодировании вероятно надо в них записать что то конкретное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теоретически порядок такой:

```js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const zlib = require('zlib');

// Encoding.

{
  const text = 'abcd\n';
  console.log(JSON.stringify(text));

  const notCompressedBuffer = Buffer.from(text);
  console.log(notCompressedBuffer);

  const compressed = zlib.gzipSync(notCompressedBuffer);
  console.log(compressed);

  const base64 = compressed.toString('base64');
  console.log(base64);

  const key = 11;
  const xorred = Buffer.from(
    Array.from(
      Buffer.from(base64),
      byte => byte ^ key
    )
  );
  console.log(xorred);

  fs.writeFileSync('test.dat', xorred, null);
}

// Decoding.

{
  const xorred = fs.readFileSync('test.dat');
  console.log(xorred);

  const key = 11;
  const base64 = Buffer.from(
    Array.from(
      xorred,
      byte => byte ^ key
    )
  ).toString();
  console.log(base64);

  const compressed = Buffer.from(base64, 'base64');
  console.log(compressed);

  const notCompressedBuffer = zlib.gunzipSync(compressed);
  console.log(notCompressedBuffer);

  const text = notCompressedBuffer.toString();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(text));
}
```

Output:

```
"abcd\n"
<Buffer 61 62 63 64 0a>
<Buffer 1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 0a 4b 4c 4a 4e e1 02 00 ac a4 8a 58 05 00 00 00>
H4sIAAAAAAAACktMSk7hAgCspIpYBQAAAA==
<Buffer 43 3f 78 42 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 48 60 7f 46 58 60 3c 63 4a 6c 48 78 7b 42 7b 52 49 5a 4a 4a 4a 4a 36 36>

<Buffer 43 3f 78 42 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 4a 48 60 7f 46 58 60 3c 63 4a 6c 48 78 7b 42 7b 52 49 5a 4a 4a 4a 4a 36 36>
H4sIAAAAAAAACktMSk7hAgCspIpYBQAAAA==
<Buffer 1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 0a 4b 4c 4a 4e e1 02 00 ac a4 8a 58 05 00 00 00>
<Buffer 61 62 63 64 0a>
"abcd\n"
```

Но это абстрактный шаблон, в вашем случае могут быть дополнительные условия.